# Find a function with certain property

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-functions

I am searching for an example of the function with the following property.

---

For given function $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,  both $e^{x}f(x)$ and $e^{-f(x)}$ are monotonically decreasing.

---

I think since $e^{-f(x)}$ is monotonically decreasing, so that $f(x)$ should increase but it does not easily come up with that kind of function which makes $e^{x}f(x)$ monotonically decreasing. How can I find the example?

**EDIT**:
The original question is after we assume the function with that kind of property, prove the function $f$ is continuous.

Comment: The product should be decreasing

Comment: I should really go to sleep

Comment: Appreciate man ^-^

Comment: But the exercise says if we assume the above function, we can prove $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about $f(x)\equiv -1$? Any constant function is monotonically increasing and monotonically decreasing!

Comment: You make my question silly. Thanks!